# Style a TextInput on React Native every time it is focused

Tags: css, react-native

I need to style (make bottom border blue) an input each time its focused.

[image: Focus on first input]

[image: Focus on fourth input]

I have this code on each one.

```
<Input
    pointerEvents="auto" 
    maxLength={1}
    editable={true}
    secureTextEntry
    style={!this.state.focus ? styles.blueBorder : styles.pinItem }
    onFocus={(e) => this.changeBorder(e, this)}
    name={0}
/>
```

changeBorder function:

```
changeBorder (e, v)  {
    !this.state.focus ? this.setState({
            focus: true
        }) : this.setState({
            focus: false
    })
}
```

styles:

```
pinItem: {
    marginHorizontal: 8,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#E5E5EA",
    elevation: 3,
    fontSize: 24,
    textAlign: "center",
    height: 58,
    width: 58,
},
blueBorder: {
    marginHorizontal: 8,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#E5E5EA",
    elevation: 3,
    fontSize: 24,
    textAlign: "center",
    height: 58,
    width: 58,
    borderBottomColor: "#0093D7",
    borderBottomWidth: 4,
},
```

So my inputs act like as follows:

[image: Click on one input]

[image: Click on another input]

As you can see, that code styles all the components each time some of them are focused. For style them separately I tried using some kind of id for each input so I can set an state object and styled them separately but I couldn't do it. I also tried to use css style for each one using some kind of css pseudo class like focus, but it also didn't work.

I'm pretty new on RN so I can't think on more ways to solve this issue. Thanks in advance for your responses.

PS: I'm using native-base components.

Comment: I don’t mean to have the solution, but I’m curious about what code you tried with `:focus` pseudo-class. Do you mind sharing all this in a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the `focus`. If you do not realize it, you have the save indicator for each textinput which is this.state.focus.

**The solution**

Easiest way is to create multiple state that will indicate each textinput.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

the way I handled this was to store the currently focused input in state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        pinFocus: null,
    }
}
```

Then add a method for getting the styles of the input:

```
pinInputStyles(focused = false){
    let styles = [baseStyles];
    if(focused === true){
        styles.push({borderColor: '#000'});
    }
    return styles;
}
```

Then on the input you do these three things for style, focus and blur (I've left additional attributes off):

```
<Input
    style={this.pinInputStyles(this.state.pinFocus === 1)}
    onBlur={ () => this.setState({pinFocus:null}) }
    onFocus={ () => this.setState({pinFocus:1}) }
/>
```

You then increment the 1 to be 2,3,4 etc for other inputs.